# In SwiftUI, how to remove list row separator when using list plus NavigatoinLink?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

If my list has no NavigationLink, it works well for hiding the list row separator

```
List {
   ForEach(listVM.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
       TaskListItemView()
           .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
   }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

However, if I add NavigationLink to the item:

```
List {
   ForEach(listVM.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
       NavigationLink(destination: TaskDetailView()) {
           TaskListItemView()
               .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
       }
   }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

The list row separator lines come up again and cannot be removed.

How to remove them in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put it down a notch like this:

```
List {
           ForEach(listVM.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
               NavigationLink(destination: TaskDetailView()) {
                   TaskListItemView()
               }
               .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
           }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
```